# Creating a stack control like this in css3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can i create a stack control like this above?. Below is what i have tried, but when i add text on either of sides it breaks.

```
  div#storage ul.storage li {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 22px;
      height: 10px;
      margin-right: 6px;
      background: green;
  }

  div#storage ul.storage li:nth-child(n+3) {
      background: lightgrey;
  }
```

http://jsbin.com/tehijapi/15/edit

How can i create a stack like this in `pure css3`.

Comment: Have you tried using pseudo elements like `ul:after` like [this](http://jsbin.com/yevufimo/1/edit)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using pseudo elements (I am assuming your content is static)

```
  ul.storage:before{
    content: 'Storage';
  }
  ul.storage:after{
    content: '25% Usage';
  }
```

[JS Bin Sample](http://jsbin.com/yevufimo/1/edit) | [JS Bin Sample with JS assigned data](http://jsbin.com/yevufimo/2/edit) (uses HTML5 data attributes)

Comment: Just now realized that your content may not be just static (because of the percentage display). In that case, you would have to use some JS to assign the values dynamically.

Comment: Thanks Harry, can you help me in this thread.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471327/reducing-the-font-size-and-width-of-containers i have to create two controls which are in same container.... thanks again harry.

Comment: @theJava: Sure mate, will check. By the way, I have added one sample for dynamic text also.